# Set Array to an Initialized, Passed-In Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

Pardon the extraordinarily basic question, but as a Java programmer this C++ error is not exactly "clicking", so to speak.

I want to create and initialize an array in one function, then pass that array to another function.  Within the receiving function, I'd like to access elements of the passed-in array.

As an (abbreviated) example:

```
class demo{
    main() {
        int members[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        example.function(members);
    }
}
```

Which would pass array `members` to the following function:

```
class example {
    int members[];

    void function(int mem[]) {
        members = mem;
    }
}
```

Which gives me the error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int [0]’
```

I want `example.members[]` to equal `demo.members[]`.  I understand why I'm getting an `int*` in `example.function`, but can't figure out how to set up the array in `class example`.

Comment: You can't pass arrays in C or C++, what you pass is a pointer to the initial element. `void function(int mem[])` really means `void function(int *mem)` [But note that that's only for function parameters] Also, arrays are not assignable.

Comment: I just want a pointer so I can access the contents of the array.  I can't figure out how to store that in class example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the private member variable `example::members` to type `int *`.

```
class Example {
    int *members;

    void function(int *mem) {
        members = mem;
    }
}

void main () {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Example ex;
    ex.function(array);
}
```

Comment: The compiler is happy with that, but how do I access the elements of the array from Example?

Comment: This design is odd though, as it leaves ownership of the container to the client of `Example`. That means you should always make sure that `Example` does not outlive that container, otherwise you will get undefined behavior when accessing its element. This makes using `Example` quite error-prone. Normally, you would let `Example` hold its own copy of the container being passed.

Comment: @AndyProwl That's true, but the way that I'm using it, that's not an issue.  Plus, we high-level programmers don't do well with manual memory management anyways. :)

Comment: @Chance: That's incorrect, memory management schemes (or, more generally, ownership policies) are very high-level design concepts ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl True, it doesn't make much sense to store it to a member variable since `Example` can outlive the original array, and then have a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Chance Which is exactly the reason why C++ programmers prefer to avoid dynamic memory allocation (because it is a low-level programming tool and can quickly complicate matters). Also why @AndyProwl has suggested using `std::vector` so you can avoid the complication that is introduced with pointers, and try to keep as much logic on the stack as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it the C++ way, and use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

class example {
    std::vector<int> members;

    void function(std::vector<int> const& mem) {
        members = mem;
    }
};
```

In C++11 you could avoid the copy when an *rvalue* is provided (such as in: `ex.function({1, 2, 3})`) by letting `function()` take its argument by value and then move it into the data member:

```
#include <vector>

class example {
    std::vector<int> members;

    void function(std::vector<int> mem) {
        members = std::move(mem);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly assign regular  array, if you really want to use regular array, you need to do it in a loop.

Try to use `std::vector` or `std::array`  ( [std::array documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) instead.

For example: `std::vector` way:

```
class example {
   std::vector<int> members;

   void function(const std::vector<int>& mem) {
      members  = mem;
   }
}
```